# why am i getting this texture artifacting

Tags: transforms, artifacts

I notice this texture is artifacting but can't seem to find what's causing it. It occurred after I joined multiple meshes together and added a transformation to that joined mesh.

But the artifacts only happen on one of the mesh out of the multiple joined and 2 totally separate meshes that sit directly under the joined mesh [3 separate meshes in total]. I made a cut-down blend file to help. The start frame is 487, the end is 500.

Blend file on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nuiDIhLUnBTWqvNqmErDoJ3Bp7AZwWRw/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: The artifacts are the "black line" on the top and the "dotted line" on the bottom model?

Comment: you are correct. i since have made a workaround by rendering each mesh separate and compositing them after @Blunder